# CSS Positioning and alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-animations, positioning

I am working on a website where I want the text to be in the center of the page (non-scroll-able page). I have the container div in the center but cannot get the text to be in the center. It is important that `h1` has `position: fixed` because of the animations that I plan on having them. [This is what I created previously](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z8HrVYZGqD80uXz-t9ZujbkufKZlTjen) Please check the video to understand what I am trying to achieve here (or previously achieved).
But it wasn't a responsive design so started to change it. Check out the code here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tanvikhade4/67vfgnte/30/)

If there's another way of achieving the animations without `h1{position:fixed}` the solutions are welcomed.

P.s I tried getting the effect with the help of `<span>` and JavaScript+jQuery but did not get satisfied with the results.

Thanks!

If you see the code there are two `h1` tags, now when the page loads I want the content of the 1st `h1` tag to `fadeInDown` and after a delay of `2s` to `fadeOutDown` (using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for this purpose) If I dont use `position:fixed` on my `h1` tags the content of each `h1` gets stacked upon each other which I don't want.

You can check the jsFiddle, I have updated it with the animations.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden
}

.content {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 80%;
  color: #ff7100;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
 
}

h1 {
position:fixed;
  /* try commenting this to see how it affects the animation (effect is not the one desired)*/
  opacity: 0
}

.main .content h1 {
 
  animation: fadeInDown, fadeOutDown;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in, linear;
}

.main .content h1:nth-child(1) {
  /* margin-left: 35%; */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s, 4s;
  animation-delay: 2s, 4s;
}

.main .content h1:nth-child(2) {
  /* margin-left: 35%; */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s, 6s;
  animation-delay: 4.5s, 6;
}

.main .content h1:nth-child(3) {
  /* margin-left: 30%; */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15.5s, 18s;
  animation-delay: 15.5s, 18s;
}

.main .content h1:nth-child(4) {
  /* margin-left: 28%; */
  animation: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18.5s;
  animation-delay: 18.5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0)
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutDown {
  from {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid main" style="border:10px solid red;">
<p> I need the 'Websites' and 'Development' in the center of the column. At the moment .text-center doesn't work 
  <div style="border:10px solid purple;width:80%;margin:15% auto ">
    <div class="content row">
      <div class="col text-center" style="border:10px solid black;">
        <h1>Websites</h1>
        <h1>Development</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

To repeat the **ISSUE** that I have here is **I can't get the `h1` in the center of the column.**

Answer (score 0):

if your page is the same sizeas the body, adding to h1

```
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
top:50%;
left:50%;
```

May be enough
also i'm curious why you can't replace fixed by absolute in your case, because centering the container serves no purpose if you are using fixed elements.

Comment: adding that just causes the animations to work in a weird way. You can try changing that in the fiddle to see what I am talking about

Comment: @TanviKhade it works fine, you just have to add the -50% -50% in your translate3D in your css animation. I am not going to give you the full code since you need to show some efforts ('I create Em' all', you know, that kind of stuff). also the edit in you question conforts me : no need to use fixed if you want to have you animation working in a div versus having it work in the body ! the absolute position is made for that !

Comment: @TanviKhade if with that you are still struggling, edit your quetion with what you have tried and ping me :) also, i don know if translate and translate3D stack or replace each other, so choose one of them (i suggest translate, because translate3D break the whole z-index thing if you don't know what you are doing) and replace the others :D

Comment: Hey @Neil thanks, but I just ended up using nested flexboxes. Now I don't have to worry about the device res nor about the animations, again thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should center your fixed `h1` relative to the page. Also defining a `position: relative` to a parent element may help in understanding the context of your h1 element using `position: absolute` as a child element

```
h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: position fixed in position relative container doesn't work at all ;)